# Handle a request error with its own paramaters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I made a GET request using axios in a web application:

```
axios({
            method: 'get',
            url: "example.com",              
            params:{
                    _id: "anId"
                }

        })
            .then((response) => {
                //do stuffs
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                // need params._id here ?!!
            })
```

Is it possible to get params in the error handling section of the request?
Thanks.

Comment: Define the params outside of the function call?

Comment: I use the request multiple times and it can be overwritten before the request complete, i need to keep it asynchronous.

Comment: hmm, a `closure` over the params won't do the job here?

Comment: wrap the request inside of a function, and define `params` in that function, then every request will have a different version of `params` and it won't be overwritten

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could close (closure) over the parameters to keep them in context:

```
function myWrapper() {
  const params = {
    a: 'a',
    b: 'b'
  }
  axios({
      method: 'get',
      url: "example.com",
      params: params

    })
    .then((response) => {
      // you have access to params here
      console.log(params.a);
      //do stuffs
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      // you have access to params here
      console.log(params.a);
      // need params._id here ?!!
    })
}
```

<strike>**Note**, This was not tested but should do the job</strike>

Here is a running example:

```js
function myWrapper() {
  const params = {
    a: 'a',
    b: 'b'
  }
  axios({
      method: 'get',
      url: "example.com",
      params: params

    })
    .then((response) => {
      // you have access to params here
      console.log(params.a);
      //do stuffs
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      // you have access to params here
      console.log('error', error.message);
      console.log('params!!', params);
      // need params._id here ?!!
    })
}

myWrapper();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.17.1/axios.js"></script>
```

Comment: The problem is that i make request multiple times with different prams, i am afraid that the second request will override the first one's params before it complete ?

Comment: pass the params to the function then. each call will get a new context